# Copiar/Mover archivos sin ruta especifica vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo un programa cuya funcion es copiar y pegar archivos, yo he utilizado  My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile() para hacerlo, y si funciona...

```
 My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(C:\ruta ejemplo\archivo1.txt, C:\ruta ejemplo 2\archivo1.txt)
```

El problema es que mi programa va a ser portable, y no se como hacer que extraiga el "archivo 1" de los archivos del programa en lugar de una ruta especifica (C:\ruta ejemplo)... Me pueden indicar como?
GRACIAS de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no sabes la ruta especifica, tienes 2 opciones para resolverlo.

1- `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath()` *(devuelve la ruta donde se esta ejecutando el programa, lo cual por defecto te serviría)*

Ejemplo:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() & archivo1.txt, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() & archivo2.txt)
```

2- En el .config del programa, podrías agregar que cuando se inicializa el programa, se guarde la ruta principal de donde se ejecuta *(Ejemplo "`C:\`")*, entonces ahí ya tendrías ese dato para ponerlo de modo de ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte y [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para organizar el código, selecciona el código y presiona [ctrl] + [k]. Mira [esta y otras funcionalidades para formatear lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) también ese mucha ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me funciono

Comment: @e2vl13 Si esta respuesta solucionó tu pregunta, por favor **recuerda [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**. Saludos.